How to give support for a desktop with task bar in yocto
I am using Poky kirkstone and building core-image-sato for image. I am trying to get a desktop screen having brand logo as wallpaper with task bar. How can I achieve it?
I hd tried adding x11, x11-base and gnome-desktop to my image IMAGE_INSTALL but nothing worked as expected. Am I missing on any MACRO to set?
Below is DISTRO_FEATURES setting -
DISTRO_FEATURES = "x11 opengl "

Take a look at adding matchbox-desktop https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/397685/

I have added Matchbox- dekstop, panel, keyboard and session but nothing helped. I can not see the task bar. I tried openbox too but no luck.
